# Echo a function variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use a variable from my function in an echo in PHP for a form.  This is an update form so I want to display current user informatoin.

My function is like this:

```
public static function current()
{
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer where counter = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $firstname = $data['firstname'];
    $lastname = $data['lastname'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

my form is trying to echo it here in the value:

```
<input class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" 
value="<?php echo !empty($firstname)?$firstname:'';?>">
```

I can't seem to get the $firstname variable to echo the users first name.  The user is called by a string in the url that uses ?id=

Comment: Your variable is not within scope of where you are trying to access it

Comment: is there no way to access the variable by using the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options,

`return` the desired value (or values) from the function

```
public static function current()
{
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer where counter = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    Database::disconnect();
    return array_intersect_key($data, array_flip(array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email')));
}

...

$user = Thing::current();
echo $user['email'];
```

OR set a static variable in your class to reference after

```
public static function current()
{
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer where counter = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    self::$firstname = $data['firstname'];
    self::$lastname = $data['lastname'];
    self::$email = $data['email'];
    Database::disconnect();
}

...

echo Thing::$firstname;
```

I'd prefer the first thing, but instead of returning an array with the details, make it into a Customer object.